# Unable to Validate Existing email Id using [Remote] data annotation attribute

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, json.net, remote-validation

I want to validate existence of Email Id in database using [Remote] data Annotation in Model.
But when I call a remote JsonResult Action method the parameter will be null and the result will be always be false and error message will be displayed. What is the problem in my code?

**Model :**

```
public class RegisterModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is Required!", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [Remote("IsEmailIdExists", "Account", ErrorMessage = "Email Id already exists in Database")]
    [Display(Name = "Email Id")]
    [RegularExpression("[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+.[A-Za-z]{2,4}", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Id")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is Required!", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [RegularExpression(@"(?=^.{8,15}$)((?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9]))^.*", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Password!")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Confirm password dose not match!")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Confirm Password is Required!")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}


public class EmailExists
    {
         public bool EmailCheck(string _email)
         {
              try
              {
                 var con = new SqlConnection();
                 con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString;
                 SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("spCheckEmail", con);
                 com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                 com.Parameters.Add("@uname", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1).Value = _email;
                 con.Open();
                 com.CommandTimeout = 120;
                 SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
                 if (reader.HasRows)
                 {
                     if (reader.Read())
                     {
                          if (reader["Active"].ToString() == "True")
                          {
                               reader.Dispose();
                               com.Dispose();
                               return true;
                          }
                          else
                          {
                               return false;
                          }
                     }
                     else
                     {
                          return false;
                     }
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     reader.Dispose();
                     com.Dispose();
                     return false;
                 }
                 con.Close();
                 com.Dispose();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
       }
   }
```

**Account Controller**

```
public JsonResult IsEmailIdExists(string EmailId) -> Always Null

{
      Model.EmailExists emailCheck = new FresherModel.EmailExists();
      if(!emailCheck.EmailCheck(EmailId))
      {
           return Json(false);
      }
      else
      {
          return Json(true);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of your property is `Email`. Change the signature of your action method to match

```
public JsonResult IsEmailIdExists(string Email)
{
  .....
```

Comment: Perfect Bro.. Jus a slight mistake and it  made me to come to SO.. :) Thank you.. :)